# Make fixed size <div> be scalable in fluid layout

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I'm seasoned webdesigner, so I don't know much about this art.

I got three  elements placed horizontally (left/center/right) which have fixed size:

```
.banner-box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and inside every div there are few images, that are centered horizontally and general style for img is:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

to make them fluid.

But since divs are not flexible, images inside them also won't change their size when resizing browser window.

Is it possible to set fixed size on any html element and still somehow make it fluid?
I know I could use percentages instead pixels, but I've got also problems with setting proper height for .banner-box using percents - box doesn't stretches to desired 400px, only to 281px.

Here's html:

```
    <div id="footer">

        <img src="footer-line.png" alt="Footer.png" />
        <p><span>some span</span> blah</p>
        <p>mail: <span>mail@domain.com</span></p>

    </div>
```

And whole css for my simple webpage:

```
html {
    background: url('mu-media-background-1920.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}


#container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 5% auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#header {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10% auto 5% auto;
}

.banner-box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}  

.banner-text {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    top: 7%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.see-more-button {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}

#virtual-studio {
    float: left;
}

#mu-animation {
    float: right;
}


#shadows {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#shadows img {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font: 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#footer p {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #AFBEA5;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}

#footer span {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #BDC9AF;
}
```

I'm preparing responsive layout, so it would be best (afaik) to use only percentages.

Comment: You're asking for something to be both a fixed size and scalable.. Unless I've misunderstood then that's logically impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good hybrid approach that has worked well for me in the past.

As you've already mentioned you could use percentage widths to build a fluid layout, and then restrict/fix specific div sizes with max and min values. So for example:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Here is a working example with the banner boxes restricted to max 300px width and min 400px height (I added some padding and borders so you can see what is going on): [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUJHn/1/)

In the end you'd still have to adjust your responsive media queries to deal with your fixed elements, but this way you'd only have to change a few min and max values.

Comment: Exactly how I do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) and define fixed widths/heights for `.banner-box` for each screen break point that you choose.

You'll have to play with the sizing and see which sizes fit best for which break points.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I **must** add media-queries, but I thought it's possible to first define general styles prepared for biggest size displays and then add some small parts to adapt to specific displays.

Also, I feel like it would be possible to use **only** percentages for  setting size for every element, but just can't figure out how..

Comment: In order to make percentages work, the parent element must have a fixed width and/or height. For example: setting `html, body: { width: 100%; height: 100% }` works because the parent element is the window which has a fixed width & height. If you have `div.parent { width: 100%; } div.parent > .child { width: 100% }` what gets rendered is a 0 width div because all the elements are relying on relative widths of a parent all the way up the tree.